# Kotlin data class No String-argument constructor with spring data rest

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring data rest with Kotlin and if I use data classes the associations via uri stops working with the error `no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value`

**Data class**

```
@Entity
data class Comment(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)     
    var id: Long = 0,
    var author: String? = null,
    var content: String? = null,

    @ManyToOne
    var post: Post? = null) {
}
```

If I use a simple class instead the association works fine.

```
@Entity
class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)     var id: Long = 0
    var author: String? = null
    var content: String? = null

    @ManyToOne
    var post: Post? = null
}
```

The association is done via a POST request `{"author":"John Doe","content":"Dummy Content", "post":"http://localhost:8080/post/33"}`

Any ideia why I have this error when I use a data class and what can I do to use the association creation via uri and keep using data classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some investigation, and turns out Spring Data Rest uses a custom Jackson module to deserialize JSON into JPA entities: it uses `PersistentEntityJackson2Module` class and using the inner class `UriStringDeserializer` to resolve the concrete entities from entity URI references, `http://localhost:8080/post/33` in your example.

Problem is, this custom deserialization only kicks in when the "standard deserialization" of Jackson is triggered: The one that uses empty constructor, then using setters to resolve & set the fields. At that moment, `UriStringDeserializer` converts the string into the concrete entity - `Post` instance of your example.

When you use a data class, the class neither has an empty constructor nor setters, therefore in `BeanDeserializer#deserializeFromObject` method of Jackson, it branches into `if (_nonStandardCreation)` being true, from there the call goes into `BeanDeserializerBase#deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault` , but not handed over to `PersistentEntityJackson2Module` anymore, and directly failing due to type mismatch between the constructor argument and the json value.

It seems you need to create a feature request for it to be implemented. If you decide to implement yourself, providing a `_delegateDeserializer` to the BeanDeserializer might be a start (not sure).

However, I don't know how JPA itself plays with data classes in the first place - after all it tracks the entity state changes, but a data class cannot have state changes. So, it might not be possible to use data classes after all - better to keep in mind.

**Note:** You probably cannot simply extend/override `PersistentEntityJackson2Module` because it is registered to multiple beans in `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`